# Where in derived class or base class should I declare friend class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, protected, friend-class

I have a derived class that implements an interface(abstract class) in C++. This interface has a couple of protected functions whose implementation are defined in derived class.

Now I'm trying to access these protected functions in derived class from an external class, by declaring the external class as a friend in derived class. However, the compiler still complains that I cannot access the protected member functions.

For example:
I have class `ConnectSession` implementing `IConnectSession`. And an external class called `SystemProcess` who wants to access protected member function `HandlePriviledgedRequest`.

In IConnectSession.h

```
class IConnectSession{
protected:
    virtual void HandlePriviledgedRequest() = 0;
}
```

In ConnectSession.h

```
class ConnectSession : public IConnectSession{
protected:
    void HandlePriviledgedRequest() override {/* func definition */}
    friend class SystemProcess;
}
```

In friend class I try to access `HandlePriviledgedRequest()`

SystemProcess.cpp

```
SystemProcess::ApplyConfiguration(){
    std::shared_ptr<IConnectSession> sessionPtr = new ConnectSession();
    sessionPtr->HandlePriviledgedRequest(); // compile error
}
```

It throws an error from compiler saying I cannot access protected members even if I have already declared `SystemProcess` as a friend. Since friend declarations are not inherited I particularly declare them in `ConnectSession`. Why does it not work and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: In general, I’d expect member functions of an interface to be public. Why are these protected?

Comment: @PeteBecker, I would like to make sure some interface methods are only called within certain classes but not in others. So the friend membership is only granted to those certain classes.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your access is thru the `IConnectSession` interface, `sessionPtr`, and your friendship is only with the derived class, not the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Access control is something that only applies at compile time.  In

```
SystemProcess::ApplyConfiguration(){
    std::shared_ptr<IConnectSession> sessionPtr = new ConnectSession();
    sessionPtr->HandlePriviledgedRequest(); // compile error
}
```

even though `sessionPtr` gets set to an instance of `ConnectSession`, its static type is `IConnectSession` and that is what access control is ran against.  Since `SystemProcess` isn't a friend of `IConnectSession` it is not allowed to access `HandlePriviledgedRequest()`.

You'll need to make it a friend of `IConnectSession` to get it to compile.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. Is it a best practice to declare friend class in both base class and derived class??

Comment: @Vince Best practice is to normally avoid friend classes as the break encapsulation and normally mean there is a tight coupling between things.  In this case though you only need to be a friend of the base since you are only accessing the interface that is provided by the base class.  You would need to be a friend of the derived class if you need to cast the base to the derived to access derived only potions.